# Pyplot polar surface plot

Tags: matplotlib, plot, limit, axes

I am new in pyplot.

I have a Cartesian surface plot:

```
# offset and omega are arrays

Z = my_function(omega,offset) # my_function give and arrays of omega.size*offset.size
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
p = ax.pcolor(offset,omega,Z.T,cmap=cm.jet,vmin=abs(Z).min(),vmax=abs(Z).max())
cb = fig.colorbar(p,ax=ax)
```

Maybe there is a more simple way to plot a surface but that the way I've found on the internet.

Well, now I want to plot `my_function` as a surface using polar coordinate, I've tried this:

```
ax2 = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
p2 = ax2.pcolor(offset,omega,Z.T,cmap=cm.jet,vmin=abs(Z).min(),vmax=abs(Z).max())
```

It kind of work, I have a surface plot but it does not take into account the limits of Y.

For example if Y is defined between -15 and 15° I only want my function to be plotted and shown between those angles and not 0 to 360° as my example is doing.

How can I do that ?

I thank you in advance for any answer.